# SSL Certificate messed DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl

I have got a certificate from *Comodo* and I wanted to add it to my website which is on a shared hosting. However, I ran into two problems:

1. I generated the CRS in my hosting panel and got a cert the file based on it. I have added the certificate in my hosting panel to the corresponding CRS. It shows the valid dates, IP, and active status, however when I go to my website there is no HTTPS.
2. After I added the certificate and activated the SSL the domain name http://mywebsite[.]se stopped working, however http://www.mywebsite[.]se works normally. I have checked the .htaccess file and there is no redirects in that.

So basically, I cannot get the SSL work and I have lost the control on http://mywebsite[.]se.

**PS:** In case it helps the website address is http://www.bitech.se

Comment: It often does help supplying the actual domain when asking a question, especially a DNS question.  In this case, I think it has given me the clue to your true problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked and both `http://bitech.se/` and `http://www.bitech.se/` are working fine.  The same page is returned for both. No redirects were returned.

`https://bitech.se/` is also working fine, the SSL is valid and has no errors.

`https://www.bitech.se/` does not work.  The TCP connection times out.

Since `www.bitech.se` and `bitech.se` resolve to different IP addresses, I suspect you have a firewall dropping packets to port 443 on the IP address `188.95.227.20` but allowing them on `188.95.231.125`.

Comment: is there any way to redirect all packets, whether heading for either IP or http to the https://bitech.se/?

Comment: Why not change your DNS records so they both point to the same IP address?

Comment: In the DNS settings I set both @ and www to 188.95.227.20.
In the .htaccess I have set the 
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]`
Now when I access the site via non-www I will get the http as usual how can I redirect http to https for non-www? I did google it but nothing this particular popped up.